# Publish to Azure from Vs2013 with 'Execute Code First Migrations' checked overwrote remote database

Tags: azure, ef-code-first, publish

While regular publish to Azure with WebDeploy, had checked Execute Code First Migrations, which i did before.
But this time the Use this connection string at runtime, was also checked, and i published without noticing it. as a result the remote azure db was wiped and instead is seeded with what looks like a default database with aspnetmemembership tables and _Migrations table that only has migrations related to identity tables.

The production data w db structures is gone and I did not yet setup backup on azure, doing it now.

Is there way to restore the database from some sort of auto backup on azure, i have web version w 1Gb size selected, I do not see any options
this suggests that web version would not have any daily backup, but also that web version is discountinued as of april, but i still have it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj650016.aspx

and another questions, i understand everything that happened? But it seems extremly dangerous that its so easy to wipe out the whole database and VS shows no warning nor publishing to azure notifies of anything. Is there anything that can be done to prevent dumb but yet very costly erros like this ?
TIA

Comment: Contact Azure support as soon as you can.  The earlier you contact them, the more chances you have to get your data back

Comment: Igor, i do not think i have Support included as MSDN based Azure plan.